# Screen is blinking when an AdMob banner is displayed in ioinc?

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, ionic4

Once the AdMob banner is displayed, it blinks the screen knowing that there is no error reporting in the console!

The screen viewing the ad includes a spinner that runs until some data are fetched from an API, so I kept the spinner loading until the Ad is present to avoid blinking, but the screen still blinks when Ad is shown.

This is a sample from my code:

```
    this.admobFree.banner.config(ConfigData.bannerAds.config);

    // autoShow = true in config.
    this.admobFree.banner.prepare().then(()=>{
           // Boolean variable that is assigned to the *ngIf directive to keep the spinner until the 
           // banner is loaded.
          // <ion-spinner name="crescent" *ngIf="!isDataLoaded&&!(isBannerLoaded)"></ion-spinner>
           isBannerLoaded=true;
});
```

What is causing the screen blink when a banner is viewed? And how to solve this?!

(**ionic 4**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is a fault in the ionic AdMob plugin where this issue is reported on the ionic forum without proposed solutions!
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/admob-screen-flash-on-load/25526

I had solved this by waiting for the AdMob banner to be shown and then display my actual view where this is controlled by using the ***ngIf** directive and a **Boolean** variable like this:

```
isContentVisible: boolean=false;
....
this.admobFree.banner.show().then(()=>{
   this.isContentVisible=true;
});
```

This will decrease the blink by 95%, but it may take some seconds to display if the internet connection is weak!

By the way the blink is slight, and will not be a clearly noticed issue, but to be professional it must be solved!

Hope the the ionic AdMob developers will solve that!